# Would a wormhole need a constant supply of negative energy?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, wormholes

According to most sources, a stable, traversable wormhole can only be created if it is stabilised using negative energy, or some other form of exotic matter. (I’m going with negative energy, because it seems the most likely to exist given our current knowledge of physics).

I was just curious to know; would a wormhole need a finite quantity of negative energy, or a constant supply, to remain open indefinitely?

Comment: The units used in the literature are Joules (energy) or kg (mass), not Watts (joules/second) nor mass flow (kg/s).